# Salesforce AppExchange app for creating Connected App

Tags: salesforce

All we want from an org is Connected App Key/Secret credentials. Is it recommended to create an AppExchange app for this? Can creating an AppExchange app allow me to create Connected App? I am required to send this information back to my server for querying Salesforce information through APIs. Currently I am requesting admin of Salesforce org to create one connected app for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an app exchange app, you just need to have the provide the Admin the callback url and the and the admin can create a connected app for your application. You may also need to provide more information depending on how the app will connect to salesforce (OAuth flow etc).  The Admin would be able to provide the Client Key and Secret that you need